# React Native Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: react-native, components, element

Im pretty new to react native and I simply cant find the mistake in my code.
I have done research. I hope someone with an experience "eye" ;) can help me.

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpc6R.png)

[AppStart.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzZ7Y.png)
[AppNavigator.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2AbU.png)

Comment: As I see you import `AppNavigator` as a **default** value, but you don't export it as one. You either should use { AppNavigator } or `export default const AppNavigator` ...

Comment: instead of a screen snapshot, copy-paste your code, it will be easy for reproducing errors if any.